# Sort strings on middle name in C++?

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I have file names in a directory (and also in an array). The file names go like this: `F1S01.C01`, `F1S03.C02`, `F1S02.C02` and so on.

The files are not sorted in this array and I would like to sort them according the example:

```
F1S01.C01
F1S02.C01
F1S03.C01
```

And:

```
F1S01.C02
F1S02.C02
F1S03.C02
```

And:

```
F1S04.C01
F1S05.C01
F1S06.C01
```

So, I always need `3` (exactly 3) file with the same "ending" e.g. `.C01` but with increasing `S01`, `S02` and `S03` (or `S04`, `S05` and `S06`). Is there a way to sort the files according to my example?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but you are supposed to show some effort. Also Title says C, while tag says C++. And if this is the only thing you need form the program neither are good tools. It's better to fallback to some scripting language.

Comment: So, what would be the way?

Comment: @Darius Please show the array definition. It is not clear whether it is a two dimensional character array or it is an array of objects of type std::string and so on.

Comment: It is just an array containing strings, not two dimensional.

Comment: All your examples are sorted by normal alphabetic order, so you can just call `std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array));` and be done with it. Otherwise provide a comparison function that reflects your order.

Answer (score -1):

I have written this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool WayToSort(string i, string j) { return i < j; };

int main()
{
vector<string>  pich = {"F1S01.C01", "F1S03.C02", "F1S02.C02", "F1S01.C02", "F1S03.C03", "F1S02.C03", "F1S01.C03", "F1S03.C01", "F1S02.C01"};
sort(pich.begin(),pich.end(),WayToSort);

  for (string &s : pich) cout << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As a result

```
F1S01.C01
F1S01.C02
F1S01.C03
F1S02.C01
F1S02.C02
F1S02.C03
F1S03.C01
F1S03.C02
F1S03.C03
```

BUT you wanted the opposite result,just change WayToSort function,probably you can use `.operator` to separate two parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's not exactly what I need, I need the .C01 to be together. So, the output should be like this:

F1S01.C01
F1S02.C01
F1S03.C01
F1S01.C02
F1S02.C02
F1S03.C02

and so on..

Sorry, didn't read your post through the end, I'll try that out!

Comment: @Darius I can give you idea,may be create struct with . between two parts.